# Custom program error 0x2e

Tags: solana-program, python, error, raydium, sendtransactionerror

I an trying to send a transaction to RAYDIUM V4 program to remove liquid from an Liquidity Pool. However, I encountered an error with code 0x2e. From here: https://github.com/raydium-io/raydium-amm/blob/master/program/src/error.rs

I found out that the error is OrderAtSlotIsPlaced. But I am unable to find where the error comes from as there is nowhere in the raydium-amm codebase produce the error.

Is there anyone have any idea about this error? Where does it come from? How to fix?

Thank you.

[image]